# How can I get my program to skip over a piece of text in java?

Tags: java, text, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

So currently I am running the following code to read from a file called Races.txt

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class FileReader {
    public FileReader(){
    }

    public static void readRaceFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        System.out.println("File found");
        int str = 0, dex = 0, con = 0, intl = 0, wis = 0, cha = 0, maxAge = 0, baseSpeed = 0;
        String name = "", size = "", description = "";
        while(reader.hasNext()){
            if(reader.hasNext("Race:")){
                reader.skip("Race:");
                reader.useDelimiter("\\{");
                name = reader.next();
                reader.skip("\nstr:");
                reader.useDelimiter(";");
                str = reader.nextInt();
                reader.skip(";\ndex:");
                dex = reader.nextInt();
                reader.skip(";\ncon:");
                con = reader.nextInt();
                reader.skip(";\nintl:");
                intl = reader.nextInt();
                reader.skip(";\nwis:");
                wis = reader.nextInt();
                System.out.println(str + wis + dex + con + intl + cha + maxAge + baseSpeed + name + size + description);
            }else if(reader.hasNext("Subrace:")){

            }
        }
        reader.close();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
            readRaceFile("Races.txt");
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("file not found");
        }
    }
}
```

That code is reading from the following text file which is formatted the same way as shown here:

```
Race:name{
str:0;
dex:0;
con:0;
intl:0;
wis:0;
cha:0;
max age:100;
base speed:35;
size:medium;
description:This is a race;
abilities:Darkvision - You can see in dim light up to 60 feet as if it were bright light, Idiosy - You are stupid;
number of possible tool proficiency choices:0;
possible tool proficiencies:brewer's tools, masonry tools;
number of possible skill proficiency choices:0;
possible skill proficiencies:perception;
number of possible language choices:0;
possible language choices:elvish, dwarf;
given tool proficiencies:martial weapons;
given skill proficiencies:;
given languages:english;
cantrips:
1, fireball
3, plant growth;
}
```

When I run the program I can successfully skip over "Race:" and import "name" and print it if I want to but when I attempt to skip "str:" by using either "\nstr:", "str:", or "{\nstr:" I receive the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.skip(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.skip(Unknown Source)
    at FileReader.readRaceFile(FileReader.java:18)
    at FileReader.main(FileReader.java:39)
```

This is one of my first Java coding projects and I realize this may be a simple fix but any additional help would be appreciated

P.S. I realize that the rest of the code is incomplete at this point but I was testing it to ensure that the scanners would work so that I could create another object that I've been working on. Thank you!

Comment: This is just my opinion, but given the (reasonably) complex nature of the data, I'd recommend having a look at XML or JSON data structures instead, which have well defined and tested APIs available, it will make your life so much simpler in the long run

Comment: Yes, if you can change your data format, you should use XML or JSON and I would recommand mapping technologies such as JAXB (with MOXy as an implementation) for XML or Jackson for JSON

Answer (score 0):

This is not the perfect way to read this file.Anyway Please check whether the following code works for you.

```
 public static void readRaceFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        System.out.println("File found");
        int str = 0, dex = 0, con = 0, intl = 0, wis = 0, cha = 0, maxAge = 0, baseSpeed = 0;
        String name = "", size = "", description = "";
        while(reader.hasNext()){
            if(reader.hasNext("Race:")){
                reader.skip("Race:");
                reader.useDelimiter("\\{");
                name = reader.next();
                reader.nextLine();
                reader.skip("str:");
                reader.useDelimiter(";");
                str = reader.nextInt();
                reader.nextLine();
                reader.skip("dex:");
                dex = reader.nextInt();
                reader.nextLine();
                reader.skip("con:");
                con = reader.nextInt();
                reader.nextLine();
                reader.skip("intl:");
                intl = reader.nextInt();
                reader.nextLine();
                reader.skip("wis:");
                wis = reader.nextInt();
                System.out.println(str + wis + dex + con + intl + cha + maxAge + baseSpeed + name + size + description);
            }else if(reader.hasNext("Subrace:")){

            }
        }
        reader.close();
    }
```

And since you are a newbie please try to read about regex pattern matching by urself to avoid this skip(pattern) of Scanner.

you can read the file into a string or you can read line by line or by using the delimiter. then apply your logic. instead of getting the logic how you have wrtten. this is super rigid and one single whitespace or a newline would screw things up.

For example you can read line by line and do operations on the String on hand rather than playing with the scanner itself.

```
public static void readRaceFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException{

             Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(filename));
             System.out.println("File found");
             while(reader.hasNext()){
                 String line = reader.nextLine();

                 //Do you work with the 'line' string as you wish.. Split the string 
                 //or applying regex anything you want to get the details in the string. 

                 //System.out.println(reader.nextLine());
             }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really use a complete parser so that it can handle more complex cases. Preferably, if you are able to change the file format, you can use an existing parser (e.g. JSON). However, if you really want to use a Scanner for this, I have outlined an approach that will work for your sample data set. Just be aware that this approach will break down when you need to include delimiters inside the data values.

```
private static final String DELIMITER = "("
+ "\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085]" // end of line
+ "|;" // semi-colons
+ "|," // commas
+ "|(?<=:)" // match after colon
+ "|(?=\\{|\\})|(?<=\\{|\\})" // match before+after brace
+ ")+"; // one or more

public static void readRaceFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException{
    try(Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(filename))) {
        reader.useDelimiter(DELIMITER);
        while(reader.hasNext()){
            String s = reader.next();
            if(s.equals("{")) {
                System.out.println("{start block}");
            } else if(s.equals("}")) {
                System.out.println("{end block}");
            } else if(s.endsWith(":")) {
                s = s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
                System.out.println("attribute: " + s);
            } else {
                s = s.trim();
                System.out.println("\tvalue: " + s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```css
attribute: Race
    value: name
{start block}
attribute: str
    value: 0
attribute: dex
    value: 0
attribute: con
    value: 0
attribute: intl
    value: 0
attribute: wis
    value: 0
attribute: cha
    value: 0
attribute: max age
    value: 100
attribute: base speed
    value: 35
attribute: size
    value: medium
attribute: description
    value: This is a race
attribute: abilities
    value: Darkvision - You can see in dim light up to 60 feet as if it were bright light
    value: Idiosy - You are stupid
attribute: number of possible tool proficiency choices
    value: 0
attribute: possible tool proficiencies
    value: brewer's tools
    value: masonry tools
attribute: number of possible skill proficiency choices
    value: 0
attribute: possible skill proficiencies
    value: perception
attribute: number of possible language choices
    value: 0
attribute: possible language choices
    value: elvish
    value: dwarf
attribute: given tool proficiencies
    value: martial weapons
attribute: given skill proficiencies
attribute: given languages
    value: english
attribute: cantrips
    value: 1
    value: fireball
    value: 3
    value: plant growth
{end block}
```